# php: name of the directory + name of the file

Tags: php, file, submit

I'm working on a form to upload files with PHP. Those are my inputs:

```
 $file_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'file_name');
 $file = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'file');
 $file_date = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'premiere_date');
 $file_director = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'director_name');
```

And this is what I don't know what am I doing wrong:

```
if ((filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit'))) { //if submit button is clicked
      $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["file_name"]);
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);    
     echo $target_file;
}
```

### And this is the html

```
 <form id="savingFiles" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Name of the file:</label>
            <input type="text" name="file_name" value="<?php if (isset($row['file_name'])) {
    echo $row['file_name'];
} ?>"/>
            <br>
              <label>Select your file:</label> 
              <input type="file" name="file" value="<?php if (isset($row['file'])) {
    echo $row['file'];
} ?>"/>
              <br>Date of premiere:
                <input type="date" name="premiere_date" value="<?php if (isset($row['premiere_date'])) {
    echo $row['premiere_date'];

} ?>"/> 
                <br>
                  <label>Name of the director:</label>
            <input type="text" name="director_name" value="<?php if (isset($row['director_name'])) {
    echo $row['director_name'];
} ?>"/>
             <br>
                  <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Upload file</button>
                  </form>

                  <?php
                  //Table with records
                  $sql = "SELECT myFilms.id, file_name, file, premiere_date, director_name FROM myFilms JOIN myFilms_directors ON myFilms.director_id = myFilms_directors.id";
                 /*for mysqlia
                  *  $result = $conn->query($sql);
                  */
                  /*for mysql (old)*/
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                  if ($result) {

                      echo "<table border='1' id='filesResults'><tr><th>FILE ID</th><th>FILE NAME</th><th>FILE</th><th>PREMIERE DATE</th><th>DIRECTOR NAME</th></tr>";


                      /* in mysqli 
                       * while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) */
                      /*for mysql (old)*/
                       while ($row =  mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                          echo '<tr><td>' . $row['id'] . '</td><td>' . $row['file_name'] . '</td><td><a href= "'. $row['file']. ' ">view file</a></td><td>' . $row['premiere_date'] . '</td><td>' . $row['director_name'] . '</td></tr>';
                      }
                      echo "</table>";
                  } else {
                      echo "there is not data on the table";
                  }
                  /*for mysqli
                  $conn->close();            
                   */
                  /*for mysql (old)*/
                  mysql_close($dbhandle);

                  ?>
```

So, When I echo $target_file, I'm expecting it to be the path in this case uploads/nameOfTheFile.pdf but it only appears as uploads/ so the $target_dir, am I using the basename function right?? I have checked on w3schools and it seems right for me, but definitely must be something wrong...

Thank you guys!!

Comment: what do you get if you call `var_dump(basename($_FILES["file"]["file_name"]));`?

Comment: good question about the double (), it was a mistake, but it does not change anything on the result, but thanks!!

Comment: with var_dump before basename I get string(0) "" 

What does that mean? I'm very new on coding so everything seems so difficult and understandable!

Comment: please update the html too.

Comment: Remove the `basename` call and just have `var_dump($_FILES["file"]["file_name"])` - what does that output?

Comment: now taking off basename it says NULL :(

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)`?

Comment: var_dump($_FILES) gives this:

array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(14) "plugin wp.docx" ["type"]=> string(71) "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" ["tmp_name"]=> string(18) "/var/tmp/phpcoayaU" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(262453) } } 

Could you explain me what can you read from here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `var_dump($_FILES)` allows you to view the entire PHP `$_FILES` associative array. As you can see from:

```
array(1) { 
    ["file"]=> array(5) { 
        ["name"]=> string(14) "plugin wp.docx" 
        ["type"]=> string(71) "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" 
        ["tmp_name"]=> string(18) "/var/tmp/phpcoayaU" 
        ["error"]=> int(0) 
        ["size"]=> int(262453) 
    } 
}
```

`$_FILES` contains one `associative array` called 'file' which has 5 indices: `name`, `type`, `tmp_name`, `error` and `size`.

You were assigning:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["file_name"]);
```

Which, refering to the object above, is incorrect as `["file_name"]` is not part of `file`. The solution should be obvious looking at the debug info, simply change `["file_name"]` to `["name"]`:

```
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Some information on PHP `var_dump()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) since you seemed unaware of this function.

Answer (score 4):

change 
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["file_name"]);
to
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

should work.

Answer (score 1):

$_FILES is an associative array which contains:

```
Array ( [name] => 
 [type] => some value 
[tmp_name] => some value
error] => some value 
[size] => some value
)
```

Change `$_FILES["file"]["file_name"]` to `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`

Comment: Thank you Chayan!!! it did work! but... Can you explain me... why??? as I don't have any 'name' as column in my db :S is called file_name

Answer (score 0):

You input file tag is associated with the name field as 'file.'

```
Instead of using $_FILES["file"]["file_name"] use this $_FILES["file"]["file"]
```

Hope it will work for you.